# is it possible to get the class of the interface <Set>

Tags: java

Am having some arguments say `(String a, Treeset b, Set c)`
and I try to get the class by `arguments[i].getClass();` of the above arguments..
is Iit possible to get the class of the interface `<Set>`.

For example:

```
Class[] argumentTypes = new Class [arguments.length];
for (int i = 0 ; i < arguments.length ; i++)
{
    argumentTypes[i] = arguments[i].getClass();
}
```

Comment: Please use spaces rather than tabs when formatting code on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you've given will find the classes of the *arguments* (i.e. the values provided to the method) - but those can never be interfaces; they'll always be concrete implementations. (You can never pass "just a set" - always a reference to an object which is an instance of an *implementation* of the interface, or a null reference.)

It sounds like you want the types of the *parameters* - which you'd get via reflection if you absolutely had to, finding the [`Method`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html) and then getting the parameters from that with [`getParameterTypes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getParameterTypes%28%29). But given that you're within the method, you already *know* the parameter types, because they're at the top of the method... I'm not sure the best way of finding "the currently executing" method, if that's what you're after.

If you're *just* trying to get the class associated with `Set`, you can use `Set.class` of course. But again, it's not really clear what you're trying to do.

EDIT: Okay, judging from your comment, there are some logical problems with what you're trying to do. Going from the *values* of arguments to which method would be invoked is impossible in the general case, because you've lost information. Consider this, for example:

```
void foo(String x) {}
void foo(Object y) {}

foo("hello"); // Calls first method
foo((Object) "hello"); // Calls second method
```

Here the argument *values* are the same - but the *expressions* have a different type.

You can find all methods which *would be valid* for the argument values - modulo generic information lost by type erasure - using `Class.isAssignableFrom`. Does that help you enough?

Note that you'll also need to think carefully about how you handle null argument values, which would obviously be valid for *any* reference type parameter...

Comment: thankz for the answer pal... actually am taking the classes and try to find  and invoke the declared method..say..Method invokeMethod = delegateClass.getDeclaredMethod(methodID,argumentTypes);
     returnObj           = invokeMethod.invoke(delegateObj,arguments);

Comment: Hi pal,, this is reverse question.... as i already said in delegate class there is getDeclaredMethod...                               Method invokeMethod = delegateClass.getDeclaredMethod(methodID,argumentTypes);               so just combine my both code.. and tell me how to find the method which had one of the argument as interface.. not class

Comment: @Meeran: You've missed my point. *You can't get the type of the argument expression from the argument value.* Please read my answer *carefully*. Imagine you were given the name "foo" and a value which is a `String` reference. Both of the methods I've presented are valid - so which one would you ask for?

Comment: the second one,consider i had a method public void findMethod(String a, set b, HashSet c)...so, can u plz tell me how to send the argument type to the method in delegate class to map the exact method..Method invokeMethod = delegateClass.getDeclaredMethod(methodID,argumentTypes);

Comment: @Meeran: The second one? Even though the value is a string? What if it had just been called as `foo("hello")`? I still think you're missing the whole point of my answer. Please read it *very* carefully. It would also help a *lot* if you would provide more context in the question, including *how* your method will be called. See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints - the more effort you put into asking a clear question, the more likely it is that people will be able to help you.

Comment: sorry for the inconvinience pal.. my question is wrong!!! i have asked another question ,,, under title.. How to Map the method having interface and class — from action to delegate ... thats the correct and exact requirement..

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getInterfaces()

Answer (score 0):

You will get the class what the caller provided.

I mean,in below class you will get HashSet.

```
Set set=new HashSet();
System.out.println(set.getClass());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two ways given below

```
Set s = new //any class that implements it for example HashSet or TreeSet etc.;
s.getClass().getName(); //This will return the name of the subclass which is refered by s.
```

or if in other way can do it

```
Set s = null;
s.getClass();//This causes NullPointer Exception
```

Comment: that means S.getClass() returns Either HashSet or Treeset.. Is ter any method to return set as such... i mean as such as interface,,

Comment: Actually i am not sure, but I don't think there is any method for such.